# Prevent listview refreshed when keyboard show/hide

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, keyboard

I notice there is strange behaviour in android.

I have a view with a list view and a search bar.

When the search bar is focused and AFTER the keyboard is shown, the items in list view adapter will call getView, that also happen again if the search bar is lost focus and BEFORE the keyboard is hidden, it cause some lag performance especially before hiding the keyboard, because it will wait until all item is refreshed.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you mentioned `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` within your project manifest?

Comment: I am having same issue. Do you remember that how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just declare keyboard configuration in your Android Manifest file. At where your Activity is defined in manifest just add one line into it as below:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity, oncreate() method, just put

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Then, in searchView.setOnQueryTextListener -> public boolean onQueryTextChange, if entered text is not in your stored list then put below lines

```
 listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //to hide the keyboard
                    methodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(getApplication().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    methodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(),0);
```

if text present then,

```
listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and reset the list adapter after any loop ends...

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope you apply neatly.